# Segmentation Fault in postgreSQL client (libpq)

Tags: c, debugging, postgresql, segmentation-fault, libpq

I'm working on a postgreSQL client application using libpq.  gcc compiles it without error.  When I run the program, however, this function:

```
void print_column(PGconn *connection) {

    PGresult *id_list;
    int row;

    // process_query() calls PQexec(), checks for errors, then returns the result
    id_list = process_query(connection, "SELECT id FROM customers WHERE state='CA'");

    for(row = 0; row < PQntuples(id_list); row++) {
        printf("%s\n", PQgetvalue(id_list, row, 0));

        // to pause the loop on each rep for debugging
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Produces the error:

```
row number 1701734765 is out of range 0..8
Segmentation fault
```

What's strange is that the for loop does the first five repetitions without a problem.  Then it causes the segmentation fault on the sixth.

I didn't post the whole program because it's 1000+ lines.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't cause the segmentation fault, but there is an error in the code you posted.

```
printf("%i\n", PQgetvalue(id_list, row, 0));
```

The `PQgetvalue` function returns a `char *`, but you're printing it as if it were an `int`.  GCC and Clang both have warnings that will complain about the type mismatch, I suggest `-Wall -Wextra` or at least `-Wall`.  You can turn on *just* the format mismatch warning by using `-Wformat`.  (This error almost certainly won't cause a segmentation fault, but it will cause incorrect output.)

But `PQgetvalue` should not cause a segmentation fault (you haven't called `PQclear`, right?).  It is possible there is an error somewhere else in your program that is corrupting memory.  You can use a tool such as Valgrind to try and detect such errors.  1000 lines isn't so long that such a problem is intractable, you can also comment out various sections with `#ifdef 0`...`#endif` until the error stops, if you're desperate.

Comment: The %i is a %s in the program.  I was having trouble with the formatting and rewrote that part before I posted.  I'll give your debugging suggestions a try and recheck my code.  I'll keep you posted.